# filter date wise, month wise and year wise data in dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

> i have added my code below, in this i wanted to add date, month, year wise data filter is it possible in this dygraph.,i don't know how to do.

```html
<html>
    <head>
  <script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/1.1.0/dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <marquee>Online Graph</marquee>
        <div id="graphdiv2"
            style="width:100%; height:50%;"></div><br>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            g2 = new Dygraph(
                             document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
                             "te1.csv", // path to CSV file
                             {            
        title: 'monitor',
                                xlabel: 'date',
                                ylabel: 'pressure',
                                legend: 'always',
                                drawPoints: true
                                 
                             } );

            </script>
          
    </body>
</html>
```

> in this it reads full data from csv and displays all, but i want to restrict it, by user click the button the graph will show like last 100 records, date wise, monthwise and year wise .,pls guide me

Comment: dygraphs displays the data you give it. If you want to do any sort of filtering, you'll need to do it in your code before handing it off to dygraphs for rendering.

Comment: this link does exactly what you want I believe http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/link-interaction

Comment: @loli that example is fulfilling my requirement. but how to add csv file in that,i tried by declaring r as csv., but not getting it .

Comment: from Dan in another question `Try requesting the csv file in your browser manually. Sometimes this happens because you get an HTML error page rather than csv data.` Basically maybe your javascript can't find/load the file, try to do it in a browser by writing the url see if it works. If not, dygraph isn't the problem.

Comment: @loli i tried loading csv in basic dyraph it works but, not in link-interaction, example i dont know were to declare  csv file and confused. pls check this link., in this i have posted all code's i used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397499/how-to-insert-csv-file-in-the-dygraph-link-interaction